# how prepare magento modules files for making extension

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system

I just created magento modules as magento module structure in my localhost magento admin. Now I want to prepare it for install via magento connect. Hence i am in troubles how combine all files as zip for individual file and prepare for extension. please anyone response please.
Thanks

Comment: You mean take your local files and put them in a ZIP file?

Comment: Do you want to make a package and available to to community like we have magentoconnect is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this url in order to package your extension and make it ready for magentoconnect

```html
http://suyati.com/how-to-package-an-extension-in-magento/
```

Please feel free to ask if you have any query